# Getting 400 Bad Request with Error code 'noResolvedUsers' when granting permission to a valid email address using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks, microsoft-graph-files

The below graph endpoint is used to grant access to the recipients on a drive item.

```
POST /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/invite
```

We are getting **400 Bad Request** with Error code **noResolvedUser**, when a valid email address is added as recipient.

```
Request Method: POST
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b\u00219b-VFEZXFE2F6XaM23GxN8X-1eQtnPNKnMeB6Rp23ucBGLuKk3pmT5OkkLL5Q1l7/items/01Q2A2TZG5GSOV2XYB7FEKPGK4VD6S7OI3/invite

Status Code: 400 Bad Request
client-request-id: e1646495-3606-4e49-88ad-2d977d284164
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json

"error": {
    "code": "noResolvedUsers",
    "message": "One or more users could not be resolved.",
    "innerError": {
        "date": "2021-06-15T08:41:35",
        "request-id": "607b3ce3-e29b-45a9-9942-7528e43fe8b4",
        "client-request-id": "e1646495-3606-4e49-88ad-2d977d284164"
    }
}
```

We could not find [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/errors) for the error code 'noResolvedError'.

Many tenants are experiencing this. Knowing what is causing this error and how to fix it will be a great help.

Comment: Please include the payload you are sending. The URI and response don't provide enough information.

Comment: Yes i agree with @MarcLaFleur - please share the payload

Comment: Thank you for responding. The payload is below.

`curl $'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/drives/b\u00219b-VFEZXFE2F6XaM23GxN8X-1eQtnPNKnMeB6Rp23ucBGLuKk3pmT5OkkLL5Q1l7/items/01Q2A2TZG5GSOV2XYB7FEKPGK4VD6S7OI3/invite' \

  --data-raw '{"recipients":[{"email":xxxxx@gmail.com}],"message":"You have been invited to the meeting \"IGNORE testing latest joining method\". Open the link to view the agenda and view meeting documents.\nThis notification was sent from XYZ™","requireSignIn":true,"sendInvitation":false,"roles":["read"]}' \`